# PIP Not working after Installing Python to /opt/ with Symbolic Link

Tags: python, pip, installation, symlink

For a variety of reasons, I installed Python 2.7 /opt

So in /opt/bin I have

```
/opt/bin/python2.7
```

I created a link after

```
sudo ln -s /opt/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I then took the pre-downloaded file get-pip, and in the folder containing it did

```
sudo python2.7 ./get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=.
```

Which gives me a Looking, Processing, and Installing Prompt before giving me

```
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip2, and pip2.7 are installed in /opt/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location

Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
```

My question is, now how do I use pip? I don't think its seeing it.  Inside my python2.7 site-packages its not there.

```
pip -V
```

gives me

```
/usr/bin/pip : No such file or directory
```

While

```
/opt/bin/pip -V
```

Gives me

```
File "/opt/bin/pip", line 5, in <odule> from pip._internal.main import main ImportError : No module named pip._internal.main
```

Any ideas? Is my link causing the problem? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: try `sudo pip` it seems you have installed python with sudo

Comment: Aha! This worked.  What did I do wrong? This is a VM so I can easily go back in time.  Is there a way I should've installed it so I dont always need to do sudo /opt/bin/pip ?

Comment: just use `sudo su -` or `sudo su -s` at VM start. Which will switch to root user.
otherwise give current user root permissions like `sudo usermod -a -G sudo hduser`

Comment: Thanks. I switched to the root user and installed everything on a VM Snapshot, but when I su username and try /opt/bin/pip -V, I still get the No module named pip._internail.main error.  If I su root and try /opt/bin/pip -V it works fine.   Why does installing it as root user not let username see it?

Comment: I think you are providing wrong location. try ```which pip``` command to get location

Comment: Both root and username for which pip return no pip in ($PATH).  However /opt/bin/pip works for root, but fails for username.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207003/discussion-between-jibril-and-mayur).